# Mysql insert from multi source

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I need to insert into table with 3 columns, 2 columns from a select and one column external.
Like this:

```
Insert into customer(username, fullname, rate) 
values
((select username, fullname from users), 1500)
```

It return : column count doesnt match

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`insert ... select` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html), with a literal value in the third column:

```
Insert into customer(username, fullname, rate) 
select username, fullname, 1500 from users
```